# How to setup VisualStudio Code to compile C# projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I want to compile my C sharp code in Visual Studio Code, but I don't know how to set up tasks.json for c#.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question there is a nice documented guide on how to use VS Code with C# [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp), and how to build projects [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).
That said, you do mention that you are new to programming.
I would recommend that you start with something more simple like [VisualStudio 2017 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/).

It's a free IDE for developing C# windows applications.
This will be a much easier starting point as all the build and code environment will be set up for you.